# Как конкретизировать ошибку, выдаваемую psycopg при заполнении БД

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

```
try:
    con = psycopg2.connect(
        database=DB_NAME, user=PG_USER, password=PG_PASS)
    con.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
    cur = con.cursor()
    result = func(cur, *args, **kwargs)
    cur.close()
    con.commit()
    return result
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)
```

Есть вот такой декоратор. Один из столбцов таблицы называется **'da'**, типа varchar. Заполняю таблицу данными. Exeption срабатывает и в консоли psycopg в трейсбек пишет **'da'**, без каких либо других уточнений. Остальные ошибки прописываются полностью.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел. В функции, которую я обернул в декоратор, была попытка взять из словаря значение по несуществующему ключу, этим ключом как раз был "da". Try/Except отловил таким образом.